# No puedo usar una variable definida

Tags: python, variables

hoy estaba haciendo un programa de piedra papel o tijera diseñado para tener varios elementos, por lo tanto este programa solo es una base y puede tener mas errores del que muestro, entonces por favor avisenme si hay otro error en el codigo
mi codigo es:

---

```
#clase
import random
class Objetos():
    id = 0
    venc_max = 0
    venc_min = 0
#\clase
#objetos

piedra = Objetos()
piedra.id = 10
piedra.venc_max = 61
piedra.venc_min = 11

papel = Objetos()
papel.id = 61
papel.venc_max = 63
papel.venc_min = 10
#\objetos









#seleccion del jugador
lista_objetos = [piedra, papel]

sel = input('elije a tu objeto')

lista_str = [0,0]

posi = 0

for obj in lista_objetos:
    lista_str[posi] = str(lista_objetos[posi])

    if str(obj) == sel:
        wsel = lista_objetos[posi]
    else:
        pass
    posi = posi + 1

#\seleccion del jugador




#seleccion pc   
ca = 0
for cb in lista_str:
    ca = ca + 1
pcsel2 = random.randint(1, ca)
pcsel = lista_objetos[pcsel2 - 1]
if pcsel.id in(range(wsel.venc_min, wsel.venc_max)):
    print('el jugador gano!')
else:
    print('la computadora gano!')
#\seleccion pc
```

---

y al ejecutarlo y elegir el elemento en el input tengo este error:

```
if pcsel.id in(range(wsel.venc_min, wsel.venc_max)):
NameError: name 'wsel' is not defined
```

aunque lo defini antes aqui:

```
for obj in lista_objetos:
    lista_str[posi] = str(lista_objetos[posi])

    if str(obj) == sel:
        wsel = lista_objetos[posi]
    else:
        pass
    posi = posi + 1
```

(lo siento por el mal formateo)
y quiero saber si lo que pasa es que dentro de los bucles for las variables no se guardan o que

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, después de entender tu lógica, logré terminar la parte de `tijeras`. Me costó un poco entender el resto del código pero llegué al resultado.

En esta primera parte lo que hice fue añadir el objeto `name` (más adelante explico para que lo hago)

```
class Objetos():
    name = ''
    id = 0
    venc_max = 0
    venc_min = 0
```

Aquí le coloco el `.lower()` para asegurarme de que será en minuscula y coincida con el `Objeto().name`

```
sel = input('Elije a tu objeto: ').lower()
```

En la parte del **for** elimino `lista_str` y `pos` ya que no serán necesarias.

Lo que habías hecho en esta línea no da el resultado que esperabas, ya que estás convirtiendo en str una clase

```
lista_str[posi] = str(lista_objetos[posi])
```

¿Qué sucede si imprimes `str(lista_objetos[0])`? ¿Crees que saldrá el valor: `'piedra'`? Pues la respuesta es la siguiente:

```
print(str(lista_objetos[0]))
#<__main__.Objetos object at 0x000001CAB7782A90>
```

Por eso agregué el objeto `name`. De esta manera, se podrá comparar directamente con lo que ha ingresado el jugador (`sel`)

Es por eso que, cuando intentabas ingresar al **if**, no podías porque `str(obj)` nunca iba a ser igual a `sel`

```
if str(obj) == sel:    #str(obj) = <__main__.Objetos object at 0x000001CAB7782A90>
    wsel = lista_objetos[posi]
```

Por lo que la variable `wsel` nunca iba a ser llamada.

Lo que hago aquí, es hacer un recorrido con un **for** a la `lista_objeto`. Cuando el nombre del objeto (`obj.name`) coincida con lo que ha ingresado el jugador, ese objeto se pasará a la variable `wsel`. Además, eliminé el `else: pass` considero que en esta parte es innecesario.

```
for obj in lista_objetos:
    if obj.name == sel:
        wsel = obj
```

Luego, esta parte la reduje a algo más simple, sin generar tantas variables. A la variable `pcsel` le agregaré un valor aleatorio que se encuentre en la `lista_objetos`.

También, le agregué una línea donde dice qué jugó la computadora, de esa manera saber si funciona el programa. Después, le agregué una restricción para cuando sea un empate. Del resto está igual.

```
pcsel = random.choice(lista_objetos)
print('\nLa computadora jugo: ', pcsel.name)
if pcsel == wsel:
    print('Empate!')
elif pcsel.id in (range(wsel.venc_min, wsel.venc_max)):
    print('\nEl jugador gano!')
else:
    print('\nLa computadora gano!')
```

Y eso ha sido todo, espero que te haya servido.

### Código completo:

```
import random

#clase
class Objetos():
    name = ''
    id = 0
    venc_max = 0
    venc_min = 0
#\clase

#objetos
piedra = Objetos()
piedra.id = 1
piedra.venc_max = 10
piedra.venc_min = 0
piedra.name = 'piedra'

papel = Objetos()
papel.id = 10
papel.venc_max = 20
papel.venc_min = 1
papel.name = 'papel'

tijeras = Objetos()
tijeras.id = 0
tijeras.venc_max = 40
tijeras.venc_min = 10
tijeras.name = 'tijeras'
#\objetos

#seleccion del jugador
lista_objetos = [piedra, papel, tijeras]

sel = input('Elije a tu objeto: ').lower()

for obj in lista_objetos:
    if obj.name == sel:
        wsel = obj
#\seleccion del jugador

#seleccion pc
pcsel = random.choice(lista_objetos)
print('\nLa computadora jugo: ', pcsel.name)
if pcsel == wsel:
    print('Empate!')
elif pcsel.id in (range(wsel.venc_min, wsel.venc_max)):
    print('\nEl jugador gano!')
else:
    print('\nLa computadora gano!')
#\seleccion pc
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio mucho

Answer (score 0):

wsel solo se define en el:

```
    if str(obj) == sel:
```

del for in. Debería tener otra asignación anterior.
Saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo pero como hago para que afuera tenga el mismo valor que en el for in?

Comment: en ese caso podrías hacerla global. Pero la cuestión es si en cualquiera de las alternativas en algún momento entra al if, habría que chequear si el if está bien hecho.

Comment: con: global tuvariable y luego definiendola ya es una variable global, es decir está en cualquier lugar del programa.